# linearlayout problem

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a weired problem with the layout of my app.
I have a listview, in which I have inserted an own layout for each item.
This works nice.

Here is a part of the inserted XML layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/days"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
            android:paddingLeft="15px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I am doing following:

```
tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
tv.setText(getString(R.string.wishlist_price) + ": " + "293.99€");
```

getString(R.string.wishlist_price) is defined in string.xml as "Price"

Now the strange thing:
For the above "293.99€" the output on the phone looks like this:

```
Price: 293.99€
```

But if I change the money, for example to 22.95€, the output looks like this:

```
Price:
22.95€
```

So it does a newline after "Price:"
I cant found out what is causing this.

I tried it with "2.99€", it gives the intended output:

```
Price: 2.99€
```

Does someone has an idea what is causing the newline in the example "22.95€"?

EDIT:
There are two linearlayout around the one above. Perhaps they cause this strange behavior:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
```

Comment: Your question text has some formatting issues. Try putting your output in a code block so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Another comment before I answer.  Don't use pixel units, always use Density Independent Pixels (`dp` or `dip`).  Your interface will scale much nicer with the different resolutions on Android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

I changed wrap_content to fill_parent:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Comment: That is weird that it was not wrapping your content properly.  It may not be readjusting when you added that text. If you don't need `wrap_content` for multiple things on one line, I would always use `fill_parent`.  If you are in API Level 8+, use `match_parent` instead.  It replaces the deprecated `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work, but using `String.format(String, Object...)` seems like a good fit for what you are doing.

First change your string `R.string.wishlist_price` to

```
<string name="wishlist_price">Price: %1$s</string>
```

and then call it using this:

```
tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
tv.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.wishlist_price), price));
```

Take a look at this for more information: [Using String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: price is a String value. What do I have to change? Your code is only working if I use an Integer value for "price"

Comment: You change the `d` to an `s` in the xml string.  Android uses a Formatter to format the string.  The reference for that is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html.

Comment: Your code is working. BUT I have still the same problem: The price "22.95€" is located under "Price:" . Do you have another idea

Comment: It seems that it only occurs, if I use for the price value something with 6 characters. With 5 or 7 characters, it is shown right to "Price:"

Comment: Now it is getting realy strange: I tried this for price value: aa.a2€
"aa." is displayed behind "Price: ". But the rest (a2€) is in a new line